# Why is my file not being recorded in JSON

Tags: python, json, save

```
    news_dict[article_id] = {
        "article_date_timestamp": article_date_timestamp,
        "article_title": article_title,
        "article_url": article_url,
        "article_desc": article_desc
    }

with open("news_dict.txt", 'w') as file:
    json.dump(news_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

The json entry does not work.

Comment: Can you properly edit your snippet ?

Comment: Use print() as debug before posting that kind of question

Comment: Use triple ` brackets for better formatting.
Example: (remove spaces between ` )
` ` `
assert 2 == 2
` ` `

Comment: Does ```get_first_news()``` is invoking ```json.dump()```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made simple solution which works based on your snippet. You can try with this. To your code I've added `default=str` in `json_dump()`

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
news_dict = {}

article_id = 1
article_date_timestamp = datetime.now()
article_title = "Title"
article_url = "http://example.com"
article_desc = "Description"


news_dict[article_id] = {
    "article_date_timestamp": article_date_timestamp,
    "article_title": article_title,
    "article_url": article_url,
    "article_desc": article_desc
    }


with open("news_dict.json", 'w') as file:
    json.dump(news_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, default=str)
```